# Inject stopwatch using c# into all dll methods using Mono.Cecil, including methods with multiple Return statements

Tags: c#, dll, mono, mono.cecil

[Case 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2EVac.png) [Case 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Evihq.png) [Case 3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Eviiu.png) [Case 4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1Wmdz.png)

**Objective:**
Using the Injector code i'm trying to inject the stopwatch methods (which are in stopwatch dll) in the desired code location of target dll, inorder to calculate the time taken by each method in the target dll which may or may not be a void method and it may have multiple return statements.

**Target dll**

```
public class targetDll
{

void func1(){
     //Inject Stopwatch_start(); method here
        int a = 3;
        int b = 4;
        int temp;
        temp = a;
        a = b;
        b =temp;
        if (a + b > 2)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("function____1");
        }
      #Stopwatch_stop()  //Inject stop time here
    }

String func2(){
      //Inject Stopwatch_start(); method here
        int a = 3;
        int b = 4;
        int c = 5;
        int temp;
        temp = a;
        a = b;
        b = c;
        c = temp;
        if (a + b > 5)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("function____2");
        //inject Stopwatch_stop() method here
          return ;
        }
        a = temp;
      //inject Stopwatch_stop(); method here
          return;
  }
}
```

**Source dll(stopwatch dll)**

```
 public  static class stopwatch_class
{
  static System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch stopwatch_obj = new System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch();

    public static void stopwatch_start()
    {
        stopwatch_obj.Start();
    }

    public static  void stopwatch_stop()
    {            
        stopwatch_obj.Stop();
        Console.WriteLine(stopwatch_obj.ElapsedMilliseconds);            
     }        
    }
 }
```

**Injector code**

```
 class Trial_injector
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var start_method = (dynamic)null;
        var stop_method = (dynamic)null;

        AssemblyDefinition target_assembly = AssemblyDefinition.ReadAssembly("targetDll.dll", 
        new ReaderParameters { ReadWrite = true });

        var target_modules = target_assembly.MainModule;
        TypeDefinition[] target_module = target_modules.Types.ToArray();

        AssemblyDefinition source_assembly = AssemblyDefinition.ReadAssembly("stopwatch.dll", new 
        ReaderParameters { ReadWrite = true });

        var source_modules = source_assembly.MainModule;
        TypeDefinition[] source_module = source_modules.Types.ToArray();


        foreach (var type in source_module)
        {
            foreach (var method in type.Methods)
            {
                if (method.Name == "stopwatch_start")
                {
                    start_method = method;
                }

                if (method.Name == "stopwatch_stop")
                {
                    stop_method = method;
                }
            }
        }

        foreach(var module_ in target_module)
        {
            foreach(var method_ in module_.Methods)
            {
               String stg="hello_world";
                var processor2 = method_.Body.GetILProcessor();
                var first_instruction = method_.Body.Instructions.First();
                var last_instruction = method_.Body.Instructions.Last();
                var ldstr = processor2.Create(OpCodes.Ldstr, stg);

                var call = processor2.Create(OpCodes.Call, method_.Module.Import(start_method));
                var call2 = processor2.Create(OpCodes.Call, method_.Module.Import(stop_method));
                processor2.InsertBefore(first_instruction, ldstr);
                processor2.InsertAfter(first_instruction, call);

                processor2.InsertBefore(last_instruction, ldstr);
                processor2.InsertBefore(last_instruction, call2);
            }
        }
        target_assembly.Write();
    }
```

Comment: What did you try ?

Comment: I tried injecting stopwatch_start() and stopwatch_stop() to the beginning and end of each method respectively in target dll . The problem is, in void method which is having an " if  body" , the stopwatch_stop() method is inserted at the end of "if body" itself and not at the end of the method @Cyril

Comment: var processor2 = method_.Body.GetILProcessor();   //This creates a new processor

var last_instruction = method_.Body.Instructions.Last();   //This moves to the last line of code

var call2 = processor2.Create(OpCodes.Call, method_.Module.Import(stop_method));   //This imports my sendstop method

processor2.InsertBefore(last_instruction, call2);    //In here i'm moving to the last instruction of the code and using call2 to call the stopwatch_Stop(); function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were almost correct with your code. There were few modifications that needed to be done.

Not sure why you need the `ldstr` opcode as it's not needed anywhere. For the call you want to have that inserted **before** the first opcode not after. As for the last instruction you could go with `InsertBefore`. So the final code could be like this:

```
foreach (var module_ in target_module)
{
    foreach (var method_ in module_.Methods)
    {
        var processor2 = method_.Body.GetILProcessor();
        var first_instruction = method_.Body.Instructions.First();
        var last_instruction = method_.Body.Instructions.Last();
        var call = processor2.Create(OpCodes.Call, method_.Module.Import(start_method));
        var call2 = processor2.Create(OpCodes.Call, method_.Module.Import(stop_method));
        processor2.InsertBefore(first_instruction, call);

        processor2.InsertBefore(last_instruction, call2);
    }
}
```

but that wouldn't work with some early returns. Why? Early returns are coded as a `br` or `br_s` opcode to the `ret` at the end of procedure and if we inject our `call` before the ret those early returns will skip that. In your example it's not needed as this code is converted to `if-else` and we have branch in both cases correctly matched. But image we have code like this:

```
int a = 3;
if (a == 3)
{
  return; // very early return here
}
// the rest as in original one
```

we wont see elapsed time printed for this method as return will direct the execution after our injected call. What we need to do here is to update all branch instructions that are responsible for early returns (so they jump to `ret` opcode) and point them to our call. We can do this in the following way:

```
foreach (var bodyInstruction in method_.Body.Instructions)
{
    if (bodyInstruction.OpCode != OpCodes.Br && bodyInstruction.OpCode != OpCodes.Br_S) continue;
    if (((Instruction)bodyInstruction.Operand).OpCode != OpCodes.Ret) continue;

    bodyInstruction.Operand = call2;
}
```

So what we do here is that we scan through all opcodes and see if we have a `br` or `br_s` that jumps to return we update it to jump to our call instead. Violà.

[image: Execution before and after]

Note: used `Elapsed` instead of `ElapsedMilliseconds` as the former was giving all zeros.

Full code:

```
var start_method = (dynamic) null;
var stop_method = (dynamic) null;

AssemblyDefinition target_assembly = AssemblyDefinition.ReadAssembly("target.exe", new ReaderParameters {ReadWrite = true});

var target_modules = target_assembly.MainModule;
TypeDefinition[] target_module = target_modules.Types.ToArray();


AssemblyDefinition source_assembly = AssemblyDefinition.ReadAssembly("stopwatch.dll", new ReaderParameters {ReadWrite = true});

var source_modules = source_assembly.MainModule;
TypeDefinition[] source_module = source_modules.Types.ToArray();

foreach (var type in source_module)
{
  foreach (var method in type.Methods)
  {
    if (method.Name == "stopwatch_start")
    {
      start_method = method;
    }

    if (method.Name == "stopwatch_stop")
    {
      stop_method = method;
    }
  }
}

foreach (var module_ in target_module)
{
  foreach (var method_ in module_.Methods)
  {
    var processor2 = method_.Body.GetILProcessor();
    var first_instruction = method_.Body.Instructions.First();
    var last_instruction = method_.Body.Instructions.Last();
    var call = processor2.Create(OpCodes.Call, method_.Module.Import(start_method));
    var call2 = processor2.Create(OpCodes.Call, method_.Module.Import(stop_method));
    processor2.InsertBefore(first_instruction, call);

    processor2.InsertBefore(last_instruction, call2);

    foreach (var bodyInstruction in method_.Body.Instructions)
    {
      if (bodyInstruction.OpCode != OpCodes.Br && bodyInstruction.OpCode != OpCodes.Br_S) continue;
      if (((Instruction)bodyInstruction.Operand).OpCode != OpCodes.Ret) continue;

      bodyInstruction.Operand = call2;
    }
  }
}
target_assembly.Write();
```

**self-promotion on**

I happen to recorded two videos about doing this (in a bit different way) with Mono.Cecil. You can find it [Writing simple .NET execution tracer with Mono.Cecil](https://youtu.be/Axj-Nrb_sbE) and [Instrumenting .NET assemblies to measure method's execution time in with Mono.Cecil](https://youtu.be/ME2I9aLeNzI).

**self-promotion off**